# Draw changing text in the middle of a view

Tags: ios, quartz-2d, drawrect

I need to draw text in the middle of a view, the text can be 1 letter or few words.
I am drawing the text in the `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` method.

What I want is that the text will be centered horizontally and vertically (I know how to do that). **BUT** I want the font size update according to the text length so:

a string like "S" will be drawn in a 90 points font size but "hello world" will be drawn in 30 points font size.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UILabel can be used to center vertically and horizontally. Using `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth`it can also shrink the text to fit within the label's width.

```
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
label.minimumFontSize = 10.0; // or whatever...
```

If you need more control of the size I think you have to do the positioning your self. You can use the `sizeWithFont:` and `sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:` messages on a NSString to get the size of your string with a certain font - and then figure out what size to use and where to draw it. See [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html).